# Find a linearly independent set of vectors from the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider the following subset of the complex matrices:
$$
V = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{C^{2x2}} \mid \space a+d \in \mathbb{R} \right\}
$$

Find a linearly independent set of $7$ vectors from $V$.

Would this be the same as showing that the set of vectors  form a basis for $\mathbb{C^4}$ instead of $\mathbb{C^{2x2}}$

So, would this be a correct answer? :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, \ \begin{bmatrix}i\\0\\0\\-i\end{bmatrix}, \ \begin{bmatrix}0\\i\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \ \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\i\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: $V$ is 7-dimensional as a real vector space ($V$ is not a complex vector space).

Comment: It's the right idea, but a correct answer should feature matrices in $\Bbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$, not in $\Bbb{C}^4$. Just convert the seven vectors back into matrices, and your answer will be correct.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks a lot! That helps!!